# Identify and kill stuck thread in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

We are facing issues with a long running thread in tomcat . we are using `Tomcat`-7.0.47.Tomcat manager shows Current busy threads : 200, application gets stuck due to these long running threads. We implemented StuckThreadDetectionValve in server.xml( ), but it did not help out. So we implemented custom StuckThreadDetectionValve by extending StuckThreadDetectionValve from catalina, it only goes to "constructor","initInternal",and in "invoke"(when action fires), it does not go to function "getStuckThreadNames()" even after threshold time.How to achieve the same.Is there any way to detect stuck thread and kill them?

My custom Valve is like following :

```
public class StuckThreadDetection extends StuckThreadDetectionValve { StuckThreadDetection stuckThreadDetection;

public StuckThreadDetection()
{
    System.out.println("in StuckThreadDetection constructor");

}

public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException,
        ServletException
{
    System.out.println("in invoke...");

    getNext().invoke(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void initInternal() throws LifecycleException
{
    System.out.println("In initInternal");
    super.initInternal();
}

@Override
public String[] getStuckThreadNames()
{
    System.out.println("in getStuckThreadNames...");
    String[] listStuckedThread = this.getStuckThreadNames();

    for (String threadName : listStuckedThread)
    {
        System.out.println(threadName);
    }

    return listStuckedThread;

}

@Override
public String getInfo()
{
    System.out.println("In getInfo");
    return super.getInfo();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you already done a thread dump to see what your threads are doing?